# Calling in a .txt File to populate text boxes in a flash quiz

Tags: xml, flash

I am creating a health and safety quiz to be used by engineering students.

I have been given a .txt file with 16 categories of questions within them.

I have searched for a tutorial on how to do this myself, but I just can not understand the format of the guides.

Would anyone be able to enlighten me on this subject? I am using Actionscript 3.0

Here are the first few lines of the file for reference:

```
Ref || Question || AnswerA || AnswerB || AnswerC || AnswerD || AnswerE || Correct || Answer || Type || File
1.1 || Who has responsibility for health and safety on site ? || The client and main contractor only || Self - employed contractors only and employees || Employers, employees and sub - contractors || Everyone on site no matter who employs them || || D || Everyone at work has a legal duty to look after their own health and safety. || o_4 || _
1.2 || Which of the following is correct for risk assessment ? || It is a good idea to do, but not essential || Only do it if it is a big job || It is a legal requirement and must always be done || Only needs to be done for hazardous work || || C || Risk assessments are always necessary because they show how people are likely to be harmed. || o_4 || _
1.3 || Why should regular inspections of the workplace take place ? || To check whether the working environment is safe || To check that everyone is doing their job || To prepare for a visit from an HSE Inspector || To check that all staff are present || || A || If regular inspections are not carried out, the workplace could become an unsafe place. || o_4 || _
1.4 || The letters CDM stand for : || Control of Demolition(and Management) Regulations || Construction(Demolition Management) Regulations || Construction(Design and Management) Regulations || Control of Dangerous Materials Regulations || || C || The CDM Regulations aim to ensure that health and safety is addressed in a structured and organised manner during the design, construction, maintenance and demolition phases of all projects to which the regulations apply. || o_4 || _
```

Sorry if this is confusing, if someone replies and has difficulties understanding I will gladly show you anything that you may need to further understand.

Thank you.

::EDIT:: The problem I am having is I do not understand how to even begin to call this file into my scene via Actionscript 3.0.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's not necessary to post the **entire** text file here; a small representative sample (a few lines) would be sufficient. It's also helpful if you format it so that it's readable; you can click the orange `?` at the top right to get formatting help, and preview it real-time while you enter it just below your question so you'll know how it looks when you post it. (You can [edit] it afterward to fix anything you miss, BTW.) :-)

Comment: User - Your question is quite vague.  You need to provide the portions where you are stuck. At this point your project is so far from being even near scope that it is not workable; we aren't here to do your project for you, but to answer specific questions.

Comment: Hi, Sorry JoshDM. First time :$. 

The problem I have is how to call in that file, to populate text boxes in my flash file, for example I have a scene called Question4, so from the code above it would display "The letters CDM stand for" in the Question.txt box, and then in the AnswerA.txt box it would display "Control of Demolition(and Management) Regulations. etc.

Sorry for poor layout, if it is okay I would like guidance of how to call in a .txt file into specific areas of a flash file.

Comment: Also, thank you Ken White, I apologise for the poor layout of the problem, I got exceptionally frustrated with my problem, and just threw up the question in a rush.

Very sorry, thank you for sorting out the layout for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start you off, you could use a loader to read in the data.

Create an array to store questions:

```
var questions:Array = [ ];
```

Instantiate a loader and add an event listener for when loading is complete:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("questions.txt");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(request);

loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
```

On complete, parse your data file for the `||` delimiter and store questions in an array:

```
function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    // loader data - the questions.txt file
    var data:String = event.target.data;

    // split data by newline for each question
    var lines:Array = data.split("\n");

    // for every line
    for each (var line:String in lines)
    {
        // split line by "||" delimiter
        var question:Array = line.split("||");

        // add the question to the questions array:
        questions.push({ref: question[0],
                        question: question[1],
                        answerA: question[2],
                        answerB: question[3],
                        answerC: question[4],
                        answerD: question[5],
                        answerE: question[6],
                        correct: question[7],
                        answer: question[8],
                        type: question[9],
                        file: question[10]});
    }
}
```

Now, each question is an element of your questions array.

For example, to iterate through questions:

```
for each (var question:Object in questions)
{
    trace("question: " + question.question);
    trace("answer:   " + question.answer);
    trace("type:     " + question.type);
    trace("file:     " + question.file);
}
```

Or, to select a question at random:

```
var question:Object = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];

trace("question: " + question.question);
trace("answer:   " + question.answer);
trace("type:     " + question.type);
trace("file:     " + question.file);
```